# magento read mysql connection info from app/etc/local.xml and connect directly

Tags: magento

I need to remove img tags from 10,000 product descriptions.

I know that its the cardinal rule to use Magento's models for this however its safe to select all the attribute values and update them.

I tried using `Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')` as defined http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/ but was getting segmentation fault when I ran via CLI.

How do I use connection info in `local.xml` to go direct to MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
//my file is in /xyz subfolder, if yours is on magento root remove the ../ below

define("_MAGENTO_ROOT",dirname(__FILE__)."/../");

$file = _MAGENTO_ROOT . "app/etc/local.xml"; 

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

$host = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->host;
$username = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->username;
$password = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->password;
$dbname = $xml->global->resources->default_setup->connection->dbname;

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "select value, value_id from catalog_product_entity_text where attribute_id = 72 order by value_id asc #limit 100";

$descriptions = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($description = mysql_fetch_assoc($descriptions)) 
{ 
//update and save back to db 
}
```

this ran fast for me

Answer (score 0):

you don't need this much of manual mysql connection coding. Just include `Mage.php` file. That's enough. Like this,

```
   <?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');


$result=$read->query("select value, value_id from catalog_product_entity_text where attribute_id = 72 order by value_id asc #limit 100");
$row = $result->fetchAll();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($row);
```

If you want to update something, then you must get write permission. For this you have to include this,

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
```

That's it. If you have any doubt please comment here.

Comment: yes I know I tried using Mage::getSingleton('core/resource') as defined http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/direct-sql-queries/ but was getting segmentation fault when I ran via CLI.